# (DSAS) Baseline won't Transect Appended Shoreline

Tags: geometry, error, digital-shoreline-analysis-system, shoreline

I am trying to Transect my "Baseline" with my appended shoreline using DSAS in ArcGIS version 10.3. But this message window keep popping up every time I transect ( see attached first photo).

[image: DSAS message]

Its telling me to check out the DSAS log.txt so when I check it out this is what it says (see the 2nd attached photo) :

[image: DSAS log]

`The geometry is legal but certain of its properties cannot be computed.`

I think this is the problem but I can't seem to identify what the problem is *specifically* or what really went wrong. I thought maybe I did something wrong with my appended shoreline so I edited the  values, changed the Date configuration, everything I could possibly think of. But the message window I was talking about earlier just keep popping up. What do you think should I do?

Comment: I'm facing this problem right now, did you solve the problem?